# How to merge two objects within a unique layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, merge

I'm using `Adobe Illustrator CS6`.

I've created a Cross using tw rectangles:

[image]

It appairs like a two layers:

[image]

but I'd like to merge within a single one, so I can easily manage and move across others layers. How can I do it? Tried to select two layers, Layer menu and "Merge selected", but its grayed out, and I can't click.

Comment: Question : Why do you want to make a unique layer with different objects? I think you bring  vices, or kind of, from other programs. Illustrator is not Photoshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Illustrator different objects will always be in different sub-layers with the figure type name.

  - Grouping shapes you will get a unique sub-layer at the working layer with the group composed by two different sub-layers, each one with each shape.
  - Transforming shapes in a **Compound Shape**, you get a unique sub-layer at the working layer with the compound shape content, composed by two different sub-layers, each one with each shape.
  - Applying **Unite Pathfinder** to shapes, you get a unique sub-layer at the working layer, but you loose each independent shape.